# How to mount an USB-stick on Xubuntu?

Tags: mount, usb, xubuntu

I would like to do a bootable USB stick on Xubuntu. I installed unetbootin, downloaded iso-image but as I tried to create usb-stick, it said

```
You must first mount the USB drive /dev/sdb3 to a mountpoint. Most distributions will do this automatically after you remove and reinsert the USB drive.
```

I thought Xubuntu will mount the stick by default.

Answer (score 1):

First create a directory where you would like to mount the USB device, usually something like /mnt/usb, then run the following -

> sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/usb